Is it possible to use bluetooth for transferring files between an Android phone and a Linux computer?
I was wondering if it is possible to use bluetooth for transferring files between an Android phone and a Linux computer? Is it a bad idea, compared to FTP and abd, because no one has mentioned using bluetooth in How do I transfer files between Android and Linux over USB??

blueman exists but the success of transferring files is never guaranteed. I've had far too many Android phones which have refused to send or receive files this way. And I've never gotten to the bottom of it as Linux doesn't report any errors, just "Transfer failed".
And then the maximum transfer speed for Bluetooth is roughly 1.5 megabits per second which is just horribly slow nowadays. Wi-Fi or a direct USB connection (adb push/pull) will work several orders of magnitude faster. I.e. newer smartphones support Wi-Fi 7 which offers speeds up to 10 gigabit per second and even if you have something old and slow, i.e. 802.11n, you can easily achieve speeds up to 300Mbps via a 5GHz connection.

Yes, it is possible. How do I transfer files between Android and Linux over USB? specifically asks about USB, so it’s not surprising that no one has mentioned Bluetooth — I would only expect alternatives to USB to be mentioned if they are significantly better.
In practice, Bluetooth is far slower than USB for file transfers, so while it is possible, it’s not a good idea (assuming your phone can easily be connected to the target using USB).
Your desktop environment probably provides support for Bluetooth file transfers. For example, on GNOME, you can pair your phone, and then files transferred from your phone (using “Share” over Bluetooth) will automatically show up in your Downloads folder.

Thanks. The question also has received replies that recommended using network, specifically WLAN, by FTP, over MTP with USB. How is bluetooth compared to FTP over WLAN?

It’s also far slower than wi-fi.

Yes! you can use blueman to send and receive files using your bluetooth connection from your GDM or if you want to use the command line you have bluetoothctl.

On the odd occasion when I need to get a file to my phone (or indeed someone else's!) but have no alternative to bluetooth then blueman has filled that niche.
Not fast and maybe a bit of juggling to get to the accept transfer dialogue on the phone, but other than this it has been reliable for me and is as simple as
systemctl --user start obex
blueman-sendto --device=$phone_mac_address "$filename"

